# (1 Chronicles 1) Why is Seir ancestorial lineage Missing from amongst the Adamic lineal descendants lineage description?

Tags: genesis, hebrew-bible, genealogy, 1-chronicles

--Why does Seir's name Abruptly show up as the various Adamic lineal descendants lineage are being described?  In other words, who are the ancestors of Seir?

> 1 Chronicles 1:34-42 (NASB)
> 34 Abraham became the father of Isaac. The
> sons of Isaac were Esau and Israel. 35 The sons of Esau were Eliphaz,
> Reuel, Jeush, Jalam and Korah. 36 The sons of Eliphaz were Teman,
> Omar, [g]Zephi, Gatam, Kenaz, Timna and Amalek. 37 The sons of Reuel
> were Nahath, Zerah, Shammah and Mizzah. 38 The sons of **Seir** were
> Lotan, Shobal, Zibeon, Anah, Dishon, Ezer and Dishan. 39 The sons of
> Lotan were Hori and [h]Homam; and Lotan’s sister was Timna. 40 The
> sons of Shobal were [i]Alian, Manahath, Ebal, [j]Shephi and Onam. And
> the sons of Zibeon were Aiah and Anah. 41 The [k]son of Anah was
> Dishon. And the sons of Dishon were [l]Hamran, Eshban, Ithran and
> Cheran. 42 The sons of Ezer were Bilhan, Zaavan and [m]Jaakan. The
> sons of Dishan were Uz and Aran.

Comment: A similar record is found in Genesis 36.

Answer (score 3):

1 Chronicles (written circa 400 B.C.)

Chapters 1 to 9:34 – Genealogy of the Nation of Israel

Chapter 1 – God’s people from Adam to Jacob (= Israel)

1:1-34 – Founding Ancestors from Adam to Noah’s sons

1:35-54 – Ancestry of the Edomites

1:35-37 – Descendants of Esau

1:38-42 – Original people of Edom

It is worth noting that 1 Chronicles gives SELECTIVE genealogies.  The history focuses on the Southern Kingdom (Judah, Benjamin and Levi).

The New Living Translation Study Bible makes the following comments:

> The history of Edom is given in three components – the sons of Esau; the descendants of Seir; the kings who ruled in Edom.
>
> See Genesis 36 – Esau’s descendants (also known as Edom, who had three wives) went to Canaan and lived in the hill country of Seir.

Esau's wives were Adah (bore son Eliphaz), Oholibamah (bore Jeush, Jalam, Korah), and Basemath (his cousin, daughter of Ishmael) who bore Reual.

I don't know if this answers your question but it may be helpful for you to look at other chronologies, such as in 1 & 2 Samuel and 2 Kings chapter 1.

Source: New Living Translation Study Bible notes

Answer (score 1):

The genealogies of 1 Chronicles appear to serve something of a dual purpose:

1. Chart the lineage of Adam through Abraham to the people of Israel
2. Explain the lineage and presence of non-Israelite peoples currently present in the land around Israel.

The family of Seir (named Seir the Horite in Genesis 36:20) are a non-Abrahamic people whose lineage to Adam has not been recorded.

[Elliott suggests](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/1_chronicles/1-38.htm) that "Seir represents the indigenous inhabitants of Edom", as Mount Seir is a prominent point in the land of Edom, noted as the home of the Horites in Genesis 14:6.

[Mount Seir and the Edomites are mentioned a few more times in 1 Chronicles](https://www.gantshillurc.co.uk/ministers-blog/mount-seir-the-importance-of-mountains-in-the-bible) and then receive little attention until Obadiah, but appear to have been included here for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

1:38Seir was the patriarchal name of the pre-Edomite population of the region east and south of the Dead Sea (Gen. 36:20–30). Esau’s daughter-in-law Timna (vv. 35, 36), was the sister of Lotan and daughter of Seir. Thus the people of Seir and the descendants of Esau were related by marriage, and together these two people groups became the kingdom of Edom (v. 43).
(The word of promise bible commentary)